# Convert macro with variable args (...) to constexpr

Tags: c++, android-ndk, c++17, constexpr

How can I convert this macro into a cpp style constexpr ?

```
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TAG", __VA_ARGS__)
```

Something like this:

```
constexpr auto LOGD(...){
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TAG", __VA_ARGS__);
}
```

Obviusly the second one does not compile, I assume I have to change the syntax but can't figure out how.

Comment: Why do you want it to be `constexpr`?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
template<class... Args>
auto LOGD(const Args&... args) {
    return __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TAG", args...);
}
```

But why it should be `constexpr` is not clear. `__android_log_print` itself is not `constexpr`.

Comment: It can't be `constexpr` unless `__android_log_print()` is also `constexpr`.

Comment: I did not think about that when writing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Evg's answer, you can also write:

```
template<class... Args>
auto LOGD(Args&&... args) {
    return __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TAG", std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This supports perfect forwarding.

Comment: But why would you want to perfect forward arguments into a logger function?